# Find my Postgres text search dictionaries

Tags: postgresql

I created a thesaurus for full text search a few months back.  I just recently added some entries, and (I think) I update it like this:

```
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION english
    ALTER MAPPING FOR asciiword, asciihword, hword_asciipart
    WITH [my_thesaurus], english_stem;
```

However, I don't actually don't remember what my thesaurus was called.  How can I figure this out?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You may find it in the output of:

```
SELECT dictname FROM pg_catalog.pg_ts_dict;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use psql client, you can use the following command.

```
\dFd[+] PATTERN
```

lists text search dictionaries

Basically, you can use `\dFd+` to list all dictionaries along with their initialization options.